# Stochastic Problem

Tags: probability

Given the following situation:
99.9 percent of people have read a certain book.
99.7 percent of the people, who have read the book, can answer a certain question about it.
Of these, who did not read the book, 0.04% answer the question correctly by chance.
How big is the probability, that you have read the book, if you answered wrong?

My approach:
99.9%*0.3% have read the book and answered wrong.
0.1%*0.96% have not read the book and answered wrong.
In total: 99.9%*0.3%+0.1%*0.96% answered wrong.

So the probability should be:
(99.9%*0.3%) / (99.9%*0.3%+0.1%*0.96%)

which is the percentage of people, who have read the book and answered wrong divided by the percentage of people who answered wrong. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   Well, almost.   Check your numbers. $\mathsf P(\textrm{Read}\mid \textrm{Not-Correct}) \\= \dfrac{\mathsf P(\textrm{Read})\,\mathsf P(\textrm{Not-Correct}\mid \textrm{Read})}{\mathsf P(\textrm{Read})\,\mathsf P(\textrm{Not-Correct}\mid \textrm{Read})+\mathsf P(\textrm{Not-Read})\,\mathsf P(\textrm{Not-Correct}\mid \textrm{Not-Read})}\\ = \dfrac{99.9\%\cdot 0.3\% }{ 99.9\%\cdot 0.3\%+0.1\%\cdot \color{red}{99.96}\% } \\ \approx 74.9\%$

Comment: Thank you, this is what I got, too. This is kind of a quiz, unfortunately the answer is not accepted for some reason. Do you see another interpretation of the text?

Comment: Well, I get the same analysis, but the numerical answer rounds to $74.989$ percent $\to 75.0$ percent.  Is that possibly a problem?